# Conversion data type from Excel file to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a stored procedure to import an Excel data into SQL Server in an ASP.NET MVC application. The problem is when I run the application and upload the file, the data where the type is "date"  converted to (0001-01-01) 
the data where the type is "time" converted to (00:00:00.000000)
Here is my Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertNewEmployeeDetails1
    (@Date_d_arrivée DATE = NULL,  
     @heure_d_arrivée TIME = NULL, 
     @Poids_cam DECIMAL(18,2) = NULL,  
     @Id_cam INT = NULL,  
     @Id_qualité INT = NULL)  
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Réception_camions([Date d'arrivée], [heure d'arrivée], Poids_cam, Id_cam, Id_qualité)  
    VALUES (@Date_d_arrivée, @heure_d_arrivée, @Poids_cam, @Id_cam, @Id_qualité)  
END
```

and this is a part of my controller code:

```
var empDetails = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<Réception_camions>(sheetName) select a;

foreach (var a in empDetails)
{
    if (a.Date_d_arrivée != null )
    {
        DateTime Date = (a.Date_d_arrivée);

        TimeSpan heure = (a.heure_d_arrivée);
        decimal Pd = a.Poids_cam;
        int Id_qualité = Convert.ToInt32(a.Id_qualité);

        int result = PostExcelData(Date, heure, a.Poids_cam, a.Id_cam, a.Id_qualité);
        //...
    }
}

public int PostExcelData(DateTime Date_d_arrivée, TimeSpan heure_d_arrivée, Decimal Poids_cam, int Id_cam, int Id_qualité)
{
    Réception_phosphateEntities DbEntity = new Réception_phosphateEntities();

    var InsertExcelData = DbEntity.usp_InsertNewEmployeeDetails1(Date_d_arrivée, heure_d_arrivée, Poids_cam, Id_cam, Id_qualité );

    return InsertExcelData;
}
```

Comment: My general rule is to always do such work on the DBMS side. Most of them have decent support to read common import formats (Excel, CSV and Access Databases). Your return values are interesting, it seems like you get a simple "0" from the Excel Sheet or the attempt to parse/convert the Excel return value. And those values is what 0 in dates or times would look like. Excel uses a pretty uncommon formating for DateTimes: Times are the decimal part of a float. While Dates are counted in "days since X" (wich is not a constant and has a minor Leap Year bug).

Comment: Have you please a link to an example can help me, thanks!

Comment: Your date type is `TimeSpan`, and that's a duration, not a time. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I want to have in output Dates for the `[Date d'arrivée]` and Times  for `[heure d'arrivée]`, now I'm getting (0001-01-01) instead of (15/04/2018) that I have in my  excel file.

Comment: No one can help?